# How to get the images from sdcard and display it in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-imageview, android-sdcard

Actually I tried with this coding it's working fine.i.e., showing all the images  perfectly in emulator but coming to mobile it showing repeatedly the same image. I have attached the adapter class also

```
File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
            String strFile = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                strFile += file[i].getAbsolutePath() + " :: ";
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
            Log.i("test", strFile);
            String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
            imagecursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null,
                    null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");
            image_column_index = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
            count = imagecursor.getCount();
            imagegrid = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
            imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
            imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                        long id) {
                    System.gc();
                    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    actualimagecursor = managedQuery(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
                            null, null, null);
                    actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    actualimagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    String i = actualimagecursor
                            .getString(actual_image_column_index);
                    System.gc();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ViewImage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("filename", i);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context mContext;

            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return count;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                System.gc();
                ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
                if (convertView == null) {
                    imagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                    i.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                                    + id));
                    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(92, 92));
                } else {
                    i = (ImageView) convertView;
                }
                return i;
```

Comment: `File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
` should be `File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
`

Comment: @calsign::Still now am getting the same the problem i.e., same images are repeatedly coming...

Comment: That wasn't meant to be a fix... I'm just pointing out a syntax error. I'm surprised that it compiles at all.

Comment: @calsign::OK CALSIGN...but i din get any error so far..and this coding is running perfectly in emulator and while executing it in mobile am repestedly getting the same image...